# How to differentiate male and female mosquitoes at pupal stage?

Tags: development, sexual-dimorphism, mosquitoes

There are many differences between male and female mosquitoes in their adult stage. But for my experiment, I need mosquitoes before they mate. So I need to sort them before they develop in to an adult. The best option is to sort them in their pupal or larval stage. I tried to search the differences, but most of them were very general. So, if someone knows about it, please share your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Male and female pupae are consistently slightly different sizes. This isn't particularly obvious to look at them, but allows them to be sorted mechanically by using two sheets of rigid, waterproof material (aluminium, glass or acrylic) fixed at a slight angle to each other, and washing the pupae down between them until they get stuck. The pupal sorter in most common use is described in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1093/jmedent/17.6.567) and you can buy one commercially here:

http://johnwhock.com/products/laboratory-equipment/larval-pupal-separator/

I think I've seen a video of one in use at Virginia Tech somewhere online but I can't find it right now; I'll edit it in later.

[image: Image of larval/pupal separator]